# execution failed for the task class not found `org.postgresql.Driver`

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to run several `*.sql` scripts. My `gradle` task looks like this

```
task initdb(dependsOn: initProperties) << {
Class.forName(props.getProperty("db.driver"))
sql = Sql.newInstance(
        props.getProperty("db.url"),
        props.getProperty("db.admin"),
        props.getProperty("db.password"),
        props.getProperty("db.driver")
);
FileTree tree = null
//create database
fileTree(dir: 'src/main/sql/db', include: "0010_create_data_base.sql").each {
    sql.execute(it.text)
}
//create schema
fileTree(dir: 'src/main/sql/db', include: "0020_create_schema.sql").each {
    sql.execute(it.text)
}
//create tables
fileTree(dir: 'src/main/sql/tables', include: "**.sql").each {
    sql.execute(it.text)
}
//load data
fileTree(dir: 'src/main/sql/data', include: "**.sql").each {
    sql.execute(it.text)
}
}
```

Properties file contains

```
db.admin=admin
db.admin.password=pass
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432
```

My dependency for the driver

```
dependencies {
    //jdbc postresql
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.2-1004-jdbc4'
}
```

Also there is a classpath

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.2-1004-jdbc4'
    }
}
```

But I've got an error

[image]

What's the problem? It cannot find `.jar`?

Comment: Have You added repository under `repositories` section?

Comment: Instead of `Class.forName()`, try `getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass()`. Perhaps you don't need this line at all, as modern drivers auto-register themselves. In any case, SQL driver loading is complicated and makes assumptions that hold under Java but not Groovy (sounds weird but it's true). Hence it's probably better to move that code out of the build script into a Java task class.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser When I commented the line it said that `no suitable driver found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how it works on my machine.

I've added configuration

```
configurations {
    driver
}
```

My dependency looks like this

```
dependencies {
    driver 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.2-1003-jdbc4'
}
```

My `buildscript` dependency

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
         classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.2-1003-jdbc4'
    }
}
```

And here my `initdb` task

```
task initdb(dependsOn: initProperties) << {
URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader as URLClassLoader
configurations.driver.each { 
    File file -> loader.addURL(file.toURI().toURL())
}
Class driver = loader.loadClass(props.getProperty("db.driver")) //org.postgresql.Driver
def sql = Sql.newInstance(
        props.getProperty("db.url") + "/postgres",
        props.getProperty("db.admin"),
        props.getProperty("db.admin.password"),
        props.getProperty("db.driver")
);
FileTree tree = null
//create database
fileTree(dir: 'src/main/sql/db', include: "0010_create_data_base.sql").each {
    sql.execute(it.text)
}
//initalizing it again to new database
sql = Sql.newInstance(
        props.getProperty("db.url") + "/" + props.getProperty("db.name"),
        props.getProperty("db.admin"),
        props.getProperty("db.admin.password"),
        props.getProperty("db.driver")
);
//create schema
fileTree(dir: 'src/main/sql/db', include: "0020_create_schema.sql").each {
    sql.execute(it.text)
}
//create tables
fileTree(dir: 'src/main/sql/tables', include: "**.sql").each {
    sql.execute(it.text)
}
//load data
fileTree(dir: 'src/main/sql/data', include: "**.sql").each {
    sql.execute(it.text)
}
}
```